# Need an efficient way to, at scheduled intervals, stop a running application, then run a batch file

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I am running a Minecraft server on a currently unused PC. It works fine, but it has a memory leak that causes it to crash about every three days, pretty much par for the course. I would like to set up something that shuts it down at a scheduled time each day, then runs the batch file that gets it up and going again. I haven't really needed to automate anything that didn't come with its own scheduler in Windows 10 thus far, so I am not sure if Task Scheduler is up to the task.

I am comfortable with digging around in hidden files and using the command line, I just don't know where to start, and all of my searches end up grabbing results about shutting down or restarting Windows itself, not just the server. I can go that route if I have to, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: We are always glad to help, but what exactly do you mean by *"pretty much par for the course"* ?

Comment: Modded minecraft usually eats memory like mad, and I basically expect a certain amount of memory leakage. I would just prefer to restart it periodically to clean up, rather than letting it run until the leak gets so bad the server crashes.

Comment: So... that part isn't really directly relevant to the question- does no one know of a way to stop a process, then run a batch file, on a scheduled basis?